# can't install apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I run

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

and I get this error:

```
    Setting up apache2-mpm-worker (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3) ...
    /usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/apache2: undefined symbol: apr_thread_pool_task_owner_get
     * Starting web server apache2                                   
    /usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/apache2: undefined symbol: apr_thread_pool_task_owner_get
    Action 'start' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log is empty.

Is it possible to install a different version of apache2? Or maybe from a different source?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by removing all version 1.2 libapr files from /usr/local/lib, which were being used instead of more recent ones installed by apt to /usr/lib. I just ran

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libapr*
```

A more elegant/better solution would be to remove the old library files from there and symlinking the ones from /usr/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe post the output like this (apache on kubuntu 12.04 installed through lamp):

> **user@ubuntu:~$** `sudo dpkg -l | grep apache`
>
> apache2              2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3  Apache HTTP Server metapackage
>
> apache2-mpm-prefork  2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3  Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
>
> apache2-utils        2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3  utility programs for webservers
>
> apache2.2-bin        2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3  Apache HTTP Server common binary files
>
> apache2.2-common     2.2.22-1ubuntu1.3  Apache HTTP Server common files
>
> libapache2-mod-php5  5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
>
> **user@ubuntu:~$**

---

> > Or... 
> >     `Sudo apt-get update` 
> >     `sudo apt-get upgrade`
> >     `sudo apt-get -f install`
> >     `sudo reboot`

---

> > Or ...
> >     `sudo apt-get update`
> >     `sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils`
> >     `sudo apt-get autoremove`
> >     `sudo apt-get update`
> >     `sudo tasksel` ----> install lamp ---> follow gui
> >     `sudo reboot`

---

> > Or ...
> >     check /etc/hosts